# Change compute instance on Azure ML job

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

I need to rerun a pipeline that was created by a colleague, who has left the company.

Every time I try to resubmit the job I get the following error.

[image]

Is there a way to submit the job under a new instance I created? When I try to resubmit, there is no option to change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-pipeline#attributes-of-the-settings-key) to use the force_rerun parameter in the pipeline job YAML schema with new compute.

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
    type: pipeline
    display_name: hello_pipeline_settings
    
    settings:
      default_datastore: azureml:workspaceblobstore
      default_compute: azureml:cpu-cluster
    jobs:
      hello_job:
        command: echo 202204190 & echo "hello"
        environment: azureml:AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu:1
      world_job:
        command: echo 202204190 & echo "hello"
        environment: azureml:AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu:1
```